# How to show all posts on list view WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I tried to show all posts on WP admin.
I already did set up in the screen option.
All published posts are 225 but it shows only 64 posts.
I took some screenshots and attached them
[image].
[image]
[image]

I noticed two posts were on the same line. Could it be a problem?

Comment: You might have a `pre_get_posts` filter somewhere that limits the posts to 64. Do a search in your theme (most likely your functions.php) and see if there is a `pre_get_posts` and if there is a value of 64 for `posts_per_page`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. where can I check them?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a solution for you to set the number of posts per page programmatically, using the `edit_posts_per_page` hook which is made for:

> Filters the number of posts displayed per page when specifically listing “posts”.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_posts_per_page/

So you can put this at the end of the **functions.php** file of your theme:

```
function custom_edit_posts_per_page($posts_per_page) {
   return 500; // the number of posts per page
}
add_filter('edit_posts_per_page', 'custom_edit_posts_per_page');
```

If you do not want to change globally, you can also check for pages `if (is_admin()) { return 500; }`, or post types `if ( 'post-type' == get_post_type() ) { return 500; }` or user roles ... or anything you want.

If you are experiencing a problem, which may be caused by single posts, you should put these suspected posts to trash and check if the problem still exists. You can restore it from the trash at any time (remember posts in trash for more than 30 days might be deleted automatically). Then you should check the single fields of this post, maybe there is a problem with the field value causing your issue.

Comment: This *may* help, but doesn't solve the underlying issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But it might help to achieve "show all posts on list view". I admit it is not targeting to find the reason why only 64 posts are being displayed. Maybe it is enough solving the problem, without finding the reason it was caused by. Thanks for the comment!